# Ignore some properties in a deep watch for VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on an autosave feature for a vue app that sends data to api every time a change is made to the vue app data. Is it possible to ignore certain properties of an objected when using a vue watch? The object has multiple values that I want to watch to auto save and only 1 or 2 that would be ignore so it doesn't seem to make sense to set up a watch function for all the properties I want but instead just ignore the 1 that I don't.

This is the basic structure of the data:

```
data:{
  template: {
    name: "Template",
    id: 1,
    variables: [
      {
        name: "v1",
        color: "#fff",
        group: 1,
        isSelected: true
      },
      {
        name: "v2",
        color: "#fff",
        group: 3,
        isSelected: false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the basic watch function:

```
watch: {
  template: {
    handler: function(){
      this.save();
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

The isSelected field for the variables in the template are used for UI purposed only and I would like the watch to ignore that field changing because they don't get saved. I don't want to have to set up a watch function for every field in variables but instead do something in the watch like:

```
ignore: "template.variables.isSelected"
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible and generally not a good idea to mix data that will be persisted with temporary UI state. If you can bear the pain of refactoring you could store the isSelected in a separate structure that isn't watched? It could be an array with the same indexes as "variables" or some kind of map with the key being the name.

Comment: The api uses a parameter whitelist so it doesn't matter if I attempt to persist the isSelected field the api will strip it out. I considered creating a computed property to watch that doesn't include the isSelected field but that seems like a lot of overhead to just ignore a single field. I was hoping there was an easier way to do it.

Comment: There are two ways to go about it: computed with ignores stripped or listing all the properties you're watching separately: `watch: { 'template.a' {}, 'template.b': {}}` where you omit the ones you don't want. Another option is to use `handler(newVal, oldVal) { const diffs = getDiffs(newVal, oldVal){}}` where getDiffs can be recursive, if needed. There's no simple way and it also depends largely on the structure and size of your data. Smart use of lodash helps a lot in cases like yours but most such problems can be solved with sane data architecture.

Comment: From your description and the data you're showing, you should use a computed with ignored removed. Unless we're talking above tens of thousands or records, the overhead is negligible. Or, let me put it this way: the overhead from watching deep is way higher than the one from cloning and removing a few properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get old value for mutation object so I think creating some helper data as below `temp(save old data)` will help your problem .Then check old and new data ....

```js
var app = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data:{
  a: 1,
  template: {
    name: "Template",
    id: 1,
    variables: [
      {
        name: "v1",
        color: "#fff",
        group: 1,
        isSelected: true
      },
      {
        name: "v2",
        color: "#fff",
        group: 3,
        isSelected: false
      }
    ]
  },
  temp: {}
},
mounted: function() {
// this.template.variables[0].isSelected = false;
 this.temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.template));
 this.$set(this.template.variables[0],"isSelected", 222);
 
},
watch : {
 template: {
   handler: function(changeVal) {
     var flag = true;
     for(var i in changeVal.variables) {
       if(changeVal.variables[i].isSelected != this.temp.variables[i].isSelected) {
         flag = false;
       }
     }
     this.temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.template)); // assign changed data as old data again for next process
     if(flag) console.log("saveData");// this.save();
     else console.log("notsave");
   },
   deep: true
 }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```